# what is the reason for the following output of overloaded function?

Tags: java, oop, overloading

I was asked the output of this question in an interview, though I answered correctly I am not able to figure out the exact reason

```
class Main{

    void hello(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.println("i am object");
    }

    void hello(String str)
    {
         System.out.println("i am String");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.hello(null);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
i am String
```

Comment: Please [search before posting](/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+overload+null). More about searching [here](/help/searching).